# Dynamic redirect url from google console - oAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-oauth, owin, multi-tenant

I have created a MVC/API project to enable external authentication and worked fine for my local host url. However, I need to achieve the below.

1. I am supporting multi tenancy (same app service and different DB), so each tenant has to connect different DB based on the custom param in the MVC url
   Ex: https://localhost/tenant1,  .../tenant2, .../tenant3 etc (not going with separate subdomain at this point)
2. I am not sure if the Google Console supports the wildcard url as a return ur and not sure how to achieve that in MVC code (Ex:http://localhost/* OR {0}  .. something like that. (So dynamic input parameter will be returned back from google)

I am reading and attempting some solutions. Will update the answer here once i get the complete solution. In the meantime if anyone has any suggestions, please help me.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have updated my source code as follows:

Create session object before redirecting to the external login

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Tenant"] = "tenantname";
```

After callback read the tenant details and save in the session for subsequent DB calls based on the tenant name

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Tenant"] != null)
        {
            string sessionObj = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Tenant"] as String;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a common requirement, and is easily solved. There are two components.

Firstly, regardless of which of your many URLs your application lives at (myapp.com/tenant1, /tenant2, etc) you have a **single redirect URL** (eg myapp.com/oauthredirect).

Secondly, when starting the OAuth dance (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#redirecting), you can specify a `state` parameter which will be passed into your oauthredirect routine (eg. as `state=tenant1`). You can then use this to create a redirect back to the appropriate site URL once you have finished your user registration tasks.

Be careful when specifying your redirect URLs into the developer console. They must be a character-by-character match with the actual URL. So, foe example, you will need to specify both `http://myapp.com/oauthredirect` and `https://myapp.com/oauthredirect`. I've always found it quite useful to create a local entry in `/etc/hosts` (or the windows equivalent) so your localhost is also resolved by eg. `http://test.myapp.com`

Comment: Hi Pinoyyid, Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it. As per the current implementation, the redirection has been taken care from the MVC application (OWIN). (Mine is not a SPA application). Can you please advise me instead of State Param, can i have a Session object. I have updated my Question with the sample code. Please take a look.

Comment: You can in principle, but I would still advise using the state parameter as that is what it is for. Using a session object will work provided that your server infrastructure supports it, eg. if you are running in a cluster, can you guarantee that the session is mirrored across nodes.

Comment: Thank you. But in my case, I would be aware of the TenantName in the URL route parameter only. Ex (If the application url is launched from other wesite. Or user type the URL directly in the browser as https://mydomain1.net/tenant1. After,in the subsequent calls, app need to remember the tenant name to establish the Tenant specific DB connection and Theme based on the URL param. You already answered for my question but I am going another level to retain the tenant information for the subsequent server calls. Most of the solutions suggests Session but as you said will fail in load balanced env.

Answer (score 1):

> Authorized redirect URIs For use with requests from a web server. This
>   is the path in your application that users are redirected to after
>   they have authenticated with Google. The path will be appended with
>   the authorization code for access. Must have a protocol. **Cannot
>   contain URL fragments or relative paths.** Cannot be a public IP
>   address.

- http://localhost/google-api-php-client-samples/Analytics/Oauth2.php
- http://localhost/authorize/

You can have as many of them as you want but the wild card is not going to work.